# $\mathbb{Q}$ closed in the adeles?

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is relatively easy to see that $\mathbb{Q}$ (diagonally embedded) is dense in $\mathbb{A}_\mathrm{fin} = \hat{\prod}^{Z_p} Q_p$ (the 'finite adeles where the restricted product is only taken for the finite places $p$) so it cannot be a closed subset. My question is: can one see that the diagonal embedding of whole $\mathbb{Q}$ is *not* closed in the full adeles $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{A}_\mathrm{fin}$? Does somebody know what the closure is?

Thanks in advance,

Fabian Werner

Comment: I changed $\mathbb{A}_{fin}$ to $\mathbb{A}_\mathrm{fin}$, which I believe is standard.  (Code: \mathbb{A}_{fin} changed to \mathbb{A}_\mathrm{fin})  If letters are not set in \mathrm{} or \text{} or the like, then the italicization and spacing is what is appropriate for juxtaposed variables.

Comment: Of course you are right... lazy me, thanks for the improvement :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Recall" the following:

1. $\mathbb{Q}$ is discrete in $\mathbb{A} = \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{A}_{\text{fin}}$.
2. $\mathbb{A}$ is Hausdorff.
3. Every discrete subgroup of a Hausdorff group is closed.

Comment: erm... wait... isnt the set $\{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ discrete in $\mathbb{R}$ but not closed?

Comment: Ah, of course you are right. What I'm thinking of is restricted to subgroups. I'll edit.

Comment: The (surprisingly complicated) proof of 3 has been looked at before on MSE. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29515/why-is-every-discrete-subgroup-of-a-hausdorff-group-closed.

Comment: I found it on the internet already, thanks for pointing out the direction :D unbelievable, $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{A}_{\text{fin}}$ look so close, yet they are so far apart...

Comment: If anyone is interested: a proof of 3. can be found here: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Discrete_subgroup_implies_closed and the construction of the symmetric square root can be found here: math.uh.edu/~vern/grouprepn.pdf, prop. 5.7.