# Every discrete subgroup of a topological $T_1$ group is closed.

Tags: topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological $T_1$ group. If $H$ is a discrete subgroup of $G$, then there exists $U\in V(1)$ (here $V(1)$ is a filter of all neighborhoods of $1$) such that $U\cap H=\{1\}$.

Let $V\in V(1)$ such that $V^{-1}V \subset U$. Note that:

1. $|xV\cap H|\leq1$ because
   $$
   h = xv,h'= xv'\in xV\cap H \implies h^{-1}h'\in V^{-1}V\cap H = \{1\} \implies h = h'. 
   $$

So,
if $xV\cap H=\emptyset\implies x\notin cl(H)$. Therefore, $xV$ is a neighborhood of $x$ contained in $G\setminus H$.

How I do proof the case on what $xV\cap H = \{h\}$. I need to find a neighborhood $W$ of $x$ such that $W\cap H=\emptyset$ and concluded that $x\notin H$.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29515/why-is-every-discrete-subgroup-of-a-hausdorff-group-closed?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer your question?

Comment: @kabenyuk Nop. The case I want to prove is when G is T1.

Comment: A topological group $G$ is a $T_1$ space [if and only if](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Topological_Group_is_T1_iff_T2) $G$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @kabenyuk Thanks for the observation. I didn't know about this theorem.